# Does an electric field penetrate through glass?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I was just wondering something ridiculously simple; does an electric field penetrate through glass? Say I have a proton or charged cotton pulp ball inside a Pyrex glass container and apply an electric field on the outside, through the whole thing, do the particles 'feel' the field and will they be drawn to either of the electrodes? I was afraid of asking this for fear of being ridiculed, but here it is!

Comment: "I was afraid of asking this for fear of being ridiculed..." Any question coming from a place of true curiosity should never be ridiculed here

Comment: One thing to note, visible light is a combination of Electric and magnetic fields, were glass to be able to fully block electric fields glass wouldn't be transparent

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is "yes": if the container is glass or any other dielectric medium, an electric field goes right through it.  You can test this: put some pith balls (little bits of styrofoam will do) inside the glass container, rub a balloon on a wool coat or on the carpet, and bring the balloon close to the glass container while you watch the pith balls.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that a charge is completely surrounded by glass of any thickness. Gauss's law, in integral form, still applies to a surface surrounding the glass. The presence of the glass makes no difference for the outcome of the integral.